# Unexpected value 'IonicModule' imported by the module 'DynamicHtmlModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to trace this piece of code after throwing:

```
Unexpected value 'IonicModule' imported by the module 'DynamicHtmlModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

The code creates dynamic HTML components through templates depending on dynamically used set of modules. The code works as follows:

```
createAndCompileComponent(alertCtrl: AlertController, template: string, componentClass: any, extraImports: any[] = []): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    // Create the component using the template and the class.
    const component = Component({
        template: template
    })
    (componentClass);

    const imports = this.IMPORTS.concat(extraImports);

    // Now create the module containing the component.
    @NgModule({imports: imports, declarations: [component]})
    class DynamicHtmlModule { }

    try {
        // Compile the module and the component.
        return this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(DynamicHtmlModule).then((factories) => {
            // Do some stuff
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        let message = 'Template has some errors and cannot be displayed.';
        return Promise.reject({message: message, debuginfo: ex});
    }
}
```

the "imports" array of dependency modules consists of two parts:

1. static part:

   protected IMPORTS = [
   IonicModule, TranslateModule.forChild(), // some other locally created Modules
   ];
2. dynamic part which is `extraImports` and here is the weird part, when I logged this array in the console, it was empty !!, so I thought that maybe this specific HtmlComponent doesn't require extras, so I tried to replace it with a hard-coded empty array, and the surprise that it broke even before reaching the original error.